# JQuery total quantity of input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the total quantity as well as price, cannot seem to get the quantity part to work. I am calculating the total cubic yards as well as the price for each cubic yard. Thank You in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="page">
<ul>
    <li>Cubic Yards<span><input type="text" name="Quantity" value="" class="quantity"></span></li>
    <li>Price <span><input type="text" name="Price" value="25.50" class="price"></span></li>
    <li> Total <span><input type="text" name="Total" value="0.00" class="total"></span></li>
</ul>

<div id="foo"></div>
<input type="submit" value="ADD MORE" class="button" id="click">
<ul>
    <li>Total Cubic Yards:<input id="cubicYards" type="text" name="cubicYards" value="0"></li>
    <li>Total Price:<input id="amount" type="text" name="totalPrice" value="0.00"></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
$(".page").on("change keyup keydown paste propertychange bind mouseover", function(){
    calculateSum();
    calculateQuantity();
});

// add fields
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
$( "#foo" ).append(
'<ul>' + '\n\r' +
'<li>Cubic Yards <span><input type="text" name="Quantity" value="" class="quantity"></span></li>' + '\n\r' +
'<li>Price <span><input type="text" name="Price" value="" class="price"></span></li>' + '\n\r' +
'<li>Total <span><input type="text" name="Total" value="0.00" class="total"></span></li>' + '\n\r' +
'</ul>' 
);

$(".total").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        calculateSum();

    });
});

$(".quantity").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        calculateSum();

    });
});

});

// function    
function calculateSum() {
var sum = 0;
$(".total").each(function() {
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {

    var quantity = $(this).closest("ul").find("input.quantity:text").val();
    var price = $(this).closest("ul").find("input.price:text").val();

    var subTot = (quantity * price);

    $(this).val(subTot.toFixed(2));

    sum += parseFloat(subTot.toFixed(2));
   }
});

  $('#amount').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}




// function    
function calculateQuantity() {
var sum = 0;
$(".quantity").each(function() {
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {

    var quantity = $(this).closest("ul").find("input.quantity:text").val();


    var subTot = (quantity);

    $(this).val(subTot.toFixed(2));

    sum += parseFloat(subTot.toFixed(2));
   }
});

    $('#cubicYards').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not that it is your issue but some of your selectors are a little redundant.  For example $(this).closest("ul").find("input.quantity:text").val(); anc be replaced with $(this).closest("ul").find(".quantity").val(); since there is only one object with that classe.

Comment: `subTot` is retrieved as a string. Strings do not possess `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var quantity` selector seems redundant. Am I right to assume you want to sum up *all* your `.quantity` fields? If so, I don't understand why you'd have to traverse to the nearest `ul` first.

I did a simplified version of what I think you're trying to achieve: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wilejaqico/edit?html,js,output)

Basically I just simplified your `calculateQuantity` function to this:

```
function calculateQuantity() {
    var sum = 0;

    $(".quantity").each(function() {
        var q = parseFloat($(this).val());

        if(!isNaN(q)) {
            $(this).val(q.toFixed(2));
            sum += q;
        }
    });

    $('#cubicYards').val(sum.toFixed(2));
};
```

See if that works for you.